# Proof check: Prove that if there is a class $B$ such that $A \in B$ then $A$ is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading through *Notes on Set Theory*, 2nd ed. by Moschovakis, and this is part of an exercise on classes, which the author defines it as "either a set or a unary definite condition which is not coextensive with a set." Here, we use the definition that "a unary definite condition $P$ is coextensive with a set $A$ if the objects which satisfy it are precisely the members of $A$." We use the convention of the notation $x \in P \iff P(x)$.

> Let $A$ be a class. Prove that, if there exists a class $B$ such that $A \in B$, then $A$ is a set.

If $B$ is a set, then $\{A\}$ is a subset of $B$, and hence by the Unionset axiom $A$ is a set. Consider the case when $B$ is a proper class, i.e. an unary definite condition not coextensive with a set. In that case, we would have that $B(A)$ is true. If $A$ were a proper class, that is, an unary definite condition not coextensive with  set, this would result in a contradiction because in an axiomatic set theory an unary definite conditions is not an object (at least Moschvakis defines it this way) and hence not in the domain of $B$.Thus $A$ is not a proper class, and hence a set.

Is this proof correct? If not, any help woth solving the problem would bw greatly appreciated.

Comment: No.   Classes cannot be the element of a singleton.

Comment: @WilliamElliot They can if they’re sets.

Comment: This looks like a correct solution in the context of the slightly strange treatment of the book. The initial part “If B is a set...” can be simplified and merged with the second if you just pass to the coextensive condition.